# Are WebSockets reinventing the wheel?

Tags: networking, html, websocket

Correct me if I'm wrong...

1. We introduced firewalls in order to restrict internet access to their Corporate employees (and indirectly "protect" home users)
2. Now WebSockets allows applications to tunnel any communication over port 80.

What's the point? Should firewalls have never been invented in the first place?
If, as I expect, firewalls begin blocking all Websockets communication, what is the point of introducing them in the first place?

**UPDATE**: My mistake. I was under the false impression that WebSockets allowed arbitrary port-forwarding tunneling over port 80. It does not. WebSockets deal exclusively with opening a full-duplex communication over port 80.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> We introduced firewalls in order to restrict internet access to their Corporate employees (and indirectly "protect" home users)

Firewalls were not introduced to restrict the activities of the internal side of the network (although they can be used that way).  Firewalls were created to prevent intrusion from outside a network.

> Now WebSockets allows applications to tunnel any communication over port 80.

Applications (non-web) have always been able to tunnel anything they want over port 80, all that WebSockets allow is for Javascript to be used to intitiate a full-duplex connection between it and the server.

I guess I really don't understand why you would think that corporate networks would firewall WebSocket traffic.  All WebSocket does is allows a efficient full-duplex connection between web browser and server.

Comment: Don't WebSockets allow you to tunnel communication to arbitrary ports through port 80? That is, don't WebSockets redirect communication to local ports that are normally blocked by the firewall?

Comment: @Gili: As far as I know, there is no provision for arbitrary port forwarding.  I'm fairly sure that it just allows a connection between server and browser that is full-duplex.

Comment: My mistake. Thanks for clarifying about the port-forwarding.

Answer (score 6):

WebSockets aren't designed to be convenient for corporate security admins, they're designed to provide fast browser <-> server communication; the perspective you're taking in asking this question is thus invalid; WebSockets are great for their intended purpose, and most of the web is not behind a corporate firewall.

Many corporations now allow encrypted tunneling of arbitrary data to the internet anyway, so this is nothing new.  The risk of data exfiltration via WebSockets and the necessary countermeasures will still fall on the judgment of individual security admins based on the level of trust they have in their employees and the sensitivity of the corporate data they have access to.

Comment: +1, with minor nit: WebSockets will provide fast connections in the sense of latency. WebSockets won't have a significant advantage over HTTP for bandwidth (the smaller overhead is negligible for large transfers).

Comment: Don't WebSockets allow you to tunnel communication to arbitrary ports through port 80? That is, don't WebSockets redirect communication to local ports that are normally blocked by the firewall?

Comment: @Gill. No more than AJAX already does. That's the purpose of the WebSockets handshake, to enforce cross-origin security restrictions. The Javascript on the page can request a connection to an arbitrary host (just like an AJAX request can), but the Javascript can't fake the origin header (only the browser sets that). Web servers inside the network (where the browser is running) can refuse non-local origins. Other services inside the network will refuse the connection period because of the HTTP-like handshake (just like with an AJAX request).

Answer (score -2):

First, in the title, you imply websockets might be just an inferior reimplementation of a previous idea (which they actually are). Then, in the body text you go on a tangent about firewalls, which can be bypassed by not just websockets.

So, yes. Firewalls should have never been invented and the inventors should have foreseen the invention of websockets, or anything that uses a trusted transport which in this example port 80.

Answering your actual question, websockets are just an another *different* type of abstraction layer on your network. They are most likely not a substitute for regular sockets depending on relevant software.

Reinventing the wheel is a favorite passtime of developers, especially non-developers turned web developers. I guess it eases the pain of unwarranted inferiority complex,  caused by the realisation that basic computer literacy is not the same thing as programming ability.

Comment: -1 For suggesting that firewalls should have never been invented.

Comment: -1 for suggesting that WebSockets are an inferior implementation of something that already exists without citing the previous equivalent solution and without giving and evidence for it. And if you are implying that sockets are a superior prior invention, ever tried doing raw sockets from a browser? You can't. Even with Flash you still have to have a policy server running on the target for origin security (websockets does this inline with the handshake). And the most similar thing available, Comet, is higher overhead, higher latency, and more complicated to use.

Comment: @kanaka, I believe artificialidiot is saying that WebSockets are a reinvention of normal sockets and there is no obvious advantage of introducing WebSockets over just giving us access to normal sockets instead.

Comment: @Gill, raw socket connections from a browser without cross-origin validation (CORS) and without a protective handshake are a complete no-go. Imagine a scenario where Javascript can initiate raw socket connections: somebody injects a malicious Javascript ad into cnn.com, yahoo.com (or where ever). The Javascript connects to your company's private intranet, file-server, pick your private service. No more secrets. WebSockets gives browsers almost all the advantages of raw sockets (low latency, bi-directional) without opening a Texas size hole in Internet security domains.

Comment: @thomas, @kanaka sarcasm is lost on you

Comment: @artificialidiot: I saw it, wondered if it was sarcasm, then hoped that someone who was posting answers on a Q&A site, where people asking the questions want a real and truthful answer would not use sarcasm without stating it explicitly.

Comment: @artificialidiot, yep, your sarcasm was lost. Try smileys, or use the </sarcasm> tag. That's what Al Gore made it for. ;-)